# Google OAuth in iOS app saved to home screen

Tags: uiwebview, google-oauth

I have a web site that I just moved from Google AppEngine authentication to OAuth. The first time I logged in on my iPhone I got notified that OAuth in UIWebViews is going to stop on April 20.

https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html

I ran into this because I'd saved a shortcut to my web site to my iOS home screen. How do I work around this? I suppose I can have the login button open a new window for the OAuth authentication flow, then close the new window when authentication is complete. But that seems kind of kludgy for an application that the user has saved to the home screen, and detecting whether a user is in a UIWebView or not (so that I can determine whether to open a new window or not) is likely to be unreliable as I try to match the detection results that Google uses.

Does anyone have experience or guidance to share on how to make this user experience acceptable?

Answer (score 0):

The restrictions enforced by Google and Apple prevent an easy or graceful solution to this problem. Google won't let you use their OAuth service within a 'sandboxed' browser. And the 'sandboxed' browser on an iphone doesn't share any data (e.g. cookies or localStorage) with the non-sandboxed browser. So if you opened a new window to complete the OAuth exchange, there's no way to communicate the completion of the exchange and transfer a user ID back to the 'sandboxed' browser session.

The only solution I could find to this problem is similar to the Roku registration process: allow the user to generate a one-time code in a browser where she is currently logged in, and then enter that one-time code into the 'sandboxed' browser.  I opted to use a 6-digit code that's valid for 2 minutes, and added some additional logic to ensure that the code is generated and consumed by the same person.

This works, but the user experience isn't as good as a standard OAuth flow. And I understand Google's reason for restricting OAuth from 'sandboxed' browsers. But it hinders progressive web apps by forcing the user through additional hoops in order to use a PWA that they've saved to their home screen.